# Find class of newly appear DOM using mutation observer?

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

I want to detect what kind of item is coming after facebook's new post appear on users' feed when they scroll, I'm able to detect the new dom change but I'm stuck at mutation observer callback,

The `$(this)` isn't equal to the newly appear DOM, what I don't know what to do.

```
// Necessary for Facebooks "neverending" scrolling
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs

    var x = $(this);
    console.log(x) // I'm stuck here, what to do?
});

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe($('[id^=topnews_main_stream_]').get(0), {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

Comment: In MutationObserver callback `this` is the `observer` object itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mutations` object to filter the `type` of mutation and its `addedNodes` property will return the newly add nodes

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type == "childList") {
            console.log(mutation.addedNodes)
        }
    }); 
});
```

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
var list = document.querySelector('#form');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log(mutation.addedNodes)
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(list, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
});

setTimeout(function() {
  var data = '<a href="#" class="Yahooooooooo">Publishing options</a>';
  jQuery("#form").append(data)
}, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
</form>
```

Comment: this is correct, I figured it out too but in facebook there's no way to detect where's it's a link or photo or status. The DOM has no sign of different. sigh.

Comment: Your code worked, but there's no way to detect a post whether it's image, link or status according to the DOM in facebook.com.

Answer (score 1):

You should log variable `mutations` in `callback` function:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation);
    }); 
});
```